# In truffle, why are the accounts in testing different from the actual accounts of my mnemonics?

Tags: truffle

Say, the first account from my mnemonic yields `0x123`, how come `account[0]` from `accounts` in the Truffle test suite differs from the original?

Example:

```
const BatchTransfer = artifacts.require("BatchTransfer");

contract("BatchTransfer", (accounts) => {
    
    it("Has the correct Owner", async () => {
        const batchTransfer = await BatchTransfer.deployed();
        const owner = await batchTransfer.owner.call()
        console.log(owner)
        console.log(accounts[0])
        assert.equal(owner, "0x123", "Owner incorrect");
    
    });
});
```

When I deployed my contract (which implements `Ownable`), the contract creator is `0x123`, but in this case when I call `.owner.call()` or `accounts[0]` they both return `0xabc`. Why are they not returning `0x123`?

Comment: It should be the same. Are you sure they were deployed with the same mnemonic? It could be that there was an ownership transfer.